# Validar campo ingresar solo letras, numeros y el caracter "_" Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Buenas tardes necesito que me ayuden lo que pasa es que tengo que validar que en un campo solo se puedan ingresar numeros, letras mayusculas o minusculas, y solo el caracter "_"
he buscado en internet y no encuentro solucion espero me ayuden

hasta el momento he intentado hacer esto:

```
validarCodigoRol(email: string){
    let mailValido = false;
      'use strict';
      var EMAIL_REGEX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/;
      if (email.match(EMAIL_REGEX)){
        mailValido = true;
      }
    return mailValido;
  }
```

pero no funciona

Comment: Indica lo que has intentado, es dificil ayudar sin código. Mira [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Deja un ejemplo de entrada, seria algo como **ABCDEF_**?

Comment: si lo unico que debe permitir el ingreso es de Mayusculas,Minusculas,Numeros y el unico caracter que debe permitir es el "_" de eso no debe permitir el ingreso de nada mas

Comment: Tu *regex* está bien formateada. Si no te funciona, debe ser algún error más allá de esta función. Quizás deberías exponer más tu entorno: cuándo llamas a la función, de dónde sacas el valor `email` y qué haces con el resultado de la función.

Answer (score 1):

Esta expresión parece funcionar puede probarla aquí https://regexr.com/

[A-Za-z]+_